# Two menu bars with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to have two different menu bars with `ActionBarSherlock`: one at the top and one at the bottom of screen? I have seen it in many apps, including some system apps, but can't find the appropriate solution. Note that I want to work with both bars like with menus, not just write custom layout and work with simple views, and use them in several `Activities` in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have two different menu bars with ActionBarSherlock: one at the top and one at the bottom of screen?

Use `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` on your `<activity>` or `<application>` in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also set different styles to bottom and top bars? And how do I let the application know which menu items I want on top and which - on bottom?

Comment: Specifically with [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) there's two examples that might be helpful to take a peek at. [SplitActionItems](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/SplitActionItems.java) and [SplitActionModes](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/SplitActionModes.java).

Comment: @YuryPogrebnyak: "Can I also set different styles to bottom and top bars?" -- I suspect so, though I have not tried it. "And how do I let the application know which menu items I want on top and which - on bottom?" -- if by "menu items" you mean "action bar items", they go on the bottom. The top is reserved for your icon/logo, title, and navigation (e.g., drop-down list or custom view).